# How define images for arrows, drag and track in the new version of jScrollPane?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jscrollpane

I downloaded the last version of jScrollPanel (2.0 beta 5) but when opened **jquery.jscrollpane.css** I can't find any rules to apply images for top and down arrow, instead I found only this rule **.jspArrow**. I try to add an background image and it worked but the image shows on the top and down, how I can specify image for each side and also for **.jspTrack,.jspDrag**

Just like in the old version (v1).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see an example setting graphics on the arrow buttons here:
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/themes/lozenge/

The relevant CSS classes are `.jspArrowUp`, `.jspArrownDown`, `.jspArrowLeft` and `.jspArrowRight`. You can also do things like `.jspVerticalBar .jspArrow` if you want to share one image between both vertical arrows (like in my example).

I would recommend using Firebug to inspect the generated HTML from a scroll pane. This is the easiest way to see all the classes that have been added.